# Files upload in a loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have an application where i have to upload files through a loop. It uploads the first file but it gives an error that the `file "" does not exist.` Following is the array where I am getting files.

[image]

and following is the trace for the error.

[image]

Any idea what am I missing or what could be the problem?

**UPDATE:**

```
for($i=0; $i <=count($form_data['image']['files'])-1; $i++) {

   $file = $form_data['image']['files'][$i];
   $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

   $file->move("campaigns/$campaign->id/$package/images", $file_name);

}
```

Comment: Post the code from the `CheckoutController` that is responsible for the processing. We can't guess what's wrong with your code if we don't post it.

Comment: @Bogdan controller code added.

Comment: try for($i=0; $i <count($form_data['image']['date']); $i++) {

Comment: Why are you using `count($form_data['image']['date']) - 1` for the condition part of the `for` statement? Please explain clearly what you're trying to achieve because your code unfortunately doesn't clarify as much as I've hoped.

Comment: @Bogdan now the code is modified. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok, better now :). Which line is `53` in the `CheckoutController`? (because that's where the error originates in the stack trace)

Comment: @Bogdan here is the code on line 53 `$form_data = $request['content'][$package];`

Comment: First thing post a correct code for reference the code you have mentioned in above comment is not shown in the question. this information is not sufficient to answer. Could you show entire action code in which you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it. Here is my previous controller action which was not working.

```
public function done(Request $request){
    $packages = ['instagram', 'facebook', 'twitter'];
    foreach($packages as $package){
       // this is the line which was creating the problem
       $form_data = $request['contents'][$package];
       for($i=0; $i <=count($form_data['image']['files'])-1; $i++) {
          $file = $form_data['image']['files'][$i];
          $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
          $file->move("campaigns/$campaign->id/$package/images", $file_name);
       }
    }
}
```

To fix the problem just assign the request variable to another variable. This is because the request processes the files in the first loop and then it cannot find the files for other attributes in the next iteration.

```
public function done(Request $request){
    $packages = ['instagram', 'facebook', 'twitter'];
    // Fixed it with this line
    $contents = $request['contents'];
    foreach($packages as $package){
       $form_data = $contents[$package];
       for($i=0; $i <=count($form_data['image']['files'])-1; $i++) {
          $file = $form_data['image']['files'][$i];
          $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
          $file->move("campaigns/$campaign->id/$package/images", $file_name);
       }
    }
}
```